# 1970s Wonder Woman/Batman comic where they have to fight an evil Walt Disney

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, batman, wonder-woman

I read this in the late 1970s, but have long since lost the comic.

The villain in the story is a Walt Disney expy ([short for "exported character"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expy#Etymology_2)), and the story takes place at a serial-numbers-filed-off version of Disney World, with Micky/Minnie Mouse expy minions.

"Walt Disney" is using "Disney World" to harvest people's life energy to unnaturally preserve his life; their drained corpses are disposed of in various disaster "rides" and they are replaced with robots.  I recall one of the rides has a bunch of people getting incinerated in a lava flow. (Maybe a Mt. Vesuvius ride.)

"Walt Disney" tries to trap Wonder Woman to use her life energy as a better battery than normal people, but the good guys defeat him.

As I recall the minions had "guns" that looked something like gumball machines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect you're referring to [Wade Dazzle](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wade_Dazzle_(Earth-One)), a Walt Disney analogue that appears in [Wonder Woman Vol.1 #222](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_222)

[image]

Note gumball guns.

[image]

Comment: Was just writing an answer up to this. FWIW I found this by Google searching the title and flicking over to the images tab which showed [this page](https://comiclists.wordpress.com/tag/wonder-woman/) as the top result with the full page those panels are from.

Comment: The gumball type weapons can be seen [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/GmNQfaZg7TUBfBZvuOBqBli9r5NvF_jNUnS4k6pmyGOksQBH3eSCpt9jQTtk6g2PY2y8OJW03pl4v8FEBsq3CNIv5fk3A7EsjUNJw-L_s5eCG0m42pgOLNJJ91cMKTmU3n6Z4z6MHQ=s1600). Wonder Woman can be seen trapped [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/rlz63iHgk6cdcxNnAFm63_GDaYYYcNHax2nh3HEyqP9EXYAdgrmlcpNJlY8e7D_nXRrczksL_dhigVUsXkThIl68xhOC7lq3OT1owTh_euzqc_87eNlyfwws2TgARwGWETl3AmzpsA=s1600) with his motivations spelled out for us.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I went a slightly different route. I looked up the ['Alt Disney' trope on TV tropes](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Mr._Alt_Disney#Comic_Books) and Wade was the number one citation for Comics.

Comment: So *that's* why Disney bought Marvel and not DC, they've been holding a grudge for this one for decades...

Comment: Is it weird that the thing which bothered me most about the "draining bio-energy" technobabble is the idea that they get enough from one person to create a living clone (who presumably goes on to live a whole normal life in their place), *and* have some left over?  Sucking bio-energy, sure whatever.  But this sounds like beating the laws of thermodynamics!  (Unless the clone is only a diminished version of the original, like a "drab" in [Warbreaker](https://coppermind.net/wiki/BioChromatic_Breath#Drab))